# Windows .Net application crash watchdog

Tags: .net, windows, crash, watchdog

i'm creating a little kiosk application for a exhibition installation. i develop in .Net & C# and the computer will run Windows 7.

Now, what's the easiest way to setup some kind of watchdog that will kill the process and restart it in case it hangs. or if an exeption is caused, will close the error windows and also restart the application?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to write the kiosk application so that it won't crash or hang. Why spend time writing a watchdog, which might have its own problems, when you can spend the time making the application you're watching bulletproof?

Comment: of course i do that. i don't design the system such that crash is part of it's functionality. but in the realworld you never know - so in case it crashes (for what reason ever) i want to handle it.

Comment: I'm with @Mat- you don't wear a seatbelt because you're going to crash, you wear one because no matter how careful you are you can't *guarantee* that it won't happen...

Comment: Reminds me of the time someone in my product group said, "let's have the f5 key refresh the ui window in case it gets out of sync with the data model.". My response: "why don't we just fix the bugs that cause it get out of sync instead?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the kiosk app is started as a regular UI application as opposed to a service.

If this is the case, I would write a small shell app that is the one that is actually started and when it is launched, it will start the kiosk app as a separate process and then go into a loop where it checks on the health of the kiosk app every few seconds and then goes to sleep (thread.idle, doevents, whatever is needed).

You can check on the health of the kiosk app by retaining a reference to the process that was started and check to see if it has exited.

You could also do something as simple as have the kiosk update a small file on a regular basis through a background worker thread. The monitoring app could check on the update time of this file and, if it hasn't been updated in a specific period of time, you could assume that the kiosk app had locked up and kill the process, which would be restarted again on the next pass through the monitoring app's loop.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a watchdog: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11616/Watch-Dog